# Call IIS published web api using ajax call issue with CORS policy

Tags: ajax, asp.net-web-api

I developed a sample web application using normal(.aspx) page on the client button click following function I written for the web API call

```
function AddEmp() {  

        var Emp = {};  
        Emp.FirstName = $("#txtFirstName").val();  
        Emp.LastName = $("#txtLastName").val();           
        Emp.Company = $("#txtCompany").val();    


        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:55339/api/Emp/AddEmployees',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',  
            data: JSON.stringify(Emp),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {  
                alert(response);           
            },  
            error: function (x, e) {
            }  
        });   
    }
```

In the web API, Emp controller following function code is written for insert into the data base.

```
public string AddEmployees(Employee Emp)
    {
        connection();
        com = new SqlCommand("InsertData", con);
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FName", Emp.FirstName);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lname", Emp.LastName);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Compnay", Emp.Company);
        con.Open();
        int i = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
 }
```

on button click, I receive following error in the inspector

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:55339/api/Emp/AddEmployees' from origin 'http://localhost:2252'

 has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control 

check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I have tried the following option

```
crossDomain: true,

headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
            },
```

Nothing will work. How to resolve this issue.

Comment: is this url correct? http://localhost:55339/api/Emp/AddEmployees and http://localhost:2252 is also another app in IIS ?

Comment: You need to enable CORS for your web api https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: @HienNguyen Yes, it's correct URL only. Web API I published in IIS and aspx not published in IIS. I try with running both solution side by side but web API not hitting.

Comment: @MohsinMehmood as per link i enable  config.EnableCors(); in WebApiConfig file and in controller i put following code    [EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:2252", headers: "*", methods: "*")] but still same error receiving

Comment: @MohsinMehmood it's working for GETmethod but not working for POST

Comment: @user3279303 You need something like this: `[EnableCors(origins: "localhost:2252", headers: "*", methods: "*")]`

Comment: @MohsinMehmood after a change like this [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")] its working fine